# Can I replace the "Upgrade Network" with SQL query?

Tags: multisite, query, sql, updates, upgrade

I have a WordPress Multisite network. When the WordPress version has been updated, I have to click on "Upgrade Network" for do same thing on all subsites.

How can I replace this function with one SQL query?

Comment: You should not have to click "Upgrade Network" on each of the subsites. Are you saying that on the network admin pane you click the button, and it does not upgrade your individual ones? "Upgrade Network" shouldn't even show on the subsites.

Comment: Yes, I mean the menu in Network Admin panel, under "Updates". I need to click it only once, and it will update all subsites.